# How can I combine 4 separate bits into one 4 bit output?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, logic-gates, binary, hex

Say I hypothetically have four switches 0-3. I want each switch to represent a bit in a four bit long number, switch 0 being the first bit and switch 3 being the last. The end goal is to be able to represent 0-15 in hexadecimal with the 4 switches with a single output. How can I combine the inputs from the switches into one 4 bit output? When consulting google it seems that a multiplexer may be able to achieve this? I am not very familiar with the multiplexer or digital logic in general so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `one 4 bit output` ... the four switches are already represent one 4 bit quantity

Comment: @jsotola I mean a single output that contains all 4 bits which can be routed into a block that requires an input of four bits but only has one port. I am not sure how to describe it because most of this is new to me, but I commonly see it formatted like SW[3:0] or so.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a "parallel to serial conversion"

Comment: `only has one port` ... how many signals in this one port? (how many wires?)

Comment: Are you talking about a hardware description language (VHDL, Verilog) or do you want parallel to serial conversion?

Comment: what is the output spec?

Answer (score 2):

You need no additional logic.

You can view four 1-bit wires as one 4-bit signal.

[image]

Just make sure that you get the order correct, which bit is least significant, and so on.

Comment: I think that I may be asking the wrong thing. What I am wondering about is when I see something like B[3:0]. How would I achieve that?

Comment: So please edit your question and add information about the environment. Are you talking about a real circuit, a schematic, a schematic EDA tool, or a hardware description language like VHDL?

Comment: @BobJones: "B[3:0]" is often used in a schematic to represent 4 different wires in a bus!

Answer (score 1):

In hardware, it needs to be a Parallel to Series Output (PISO) Shift Register (SR)  or a digital 4:1 MUX.

4 bits is rather inefficient for PISO's as they are usually 8 bit devices, but let me show you how that is done.

1st you need a 5 state machine with 4 clock counts and a 5th state is a short pulse to reset the counter, by an RC delay amplified with an optional non-inverting gate to create a full amplitude pulse ( but isn't necessary) It only has to load , LD  the switch input data (LD) into the PISO to be ready for the next clock pulse.

This can be done in many ways.  I'll show you the old-school way with a Johnson (Ring)Counter and a PISO SR. But it could also be done with all D FFs or a PAL or in software.

My design and [Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l3BWEBmGBGZA2AHF72c0BOTTEBSc8yhAUwFo00AoNAkfbEAFi5K97hIFDuATdmAdw74eXTiHrdKkZgBkOmbiCYQC2tGC6U0IAGYBDADYBnWlVUaiCCGm7bnrzCp3nrdh3UdNAB2MjcDUPDvKFjLW3skR2D3HVSmdJiTPwTAjSZDNMjCtCzfeICkoLRIbBN02pMy0wrEqFZMZBRUrRQiCF7wmlifUZH2gHMeWp0jaa4IkakOGcMuUgM51WkKbWQIXZ0yVQAlcBJFZXB9y+zXOHBoJDAnkafl5FSLsAuL7fOyEpKD8yH9lnUFnMISt2tIFECAbdYSBMBc6jJ5CpwbJdJpIhB-oYruiMDgYf9DqUURcqYTIIJFjUqYs6cyvtgDKl-kQOUUQJ4+aoAB46SBzZkYEI6Ig8cDabAAHRsACMAJYAFyVAAUAJIAZQA8swRdwEKY3GROl03DLtGBtAApAD2AAsAHY2J1upUAYSdAFc3eraAAnZgh6nREAhFxHWI1eBwZgAY2jsapMYggkoyGgyAYMpgPx+RFq4iM2DAyAQ1agsEgLCmmbkaYG2ixaBEzcx8l8BPIQWblBwYxa-ja-2h6Kn7TAkClyDCKAgi8BVO0mpsAG8ACIhAC+zDnUuUXBup9iG6Vu8wh+PPCu56ujDIV+3O4Qd-nPBCK6zv8vEBN13bgvylSkyEOe1ZRDWg7HVZZUSjJDyWYJ00mXS8agOOtEyIMIEEwMAknADCuh9KwnWTABrNDgkwyhuGwhx607IiSNcUwugARQkdCagYnhmKSes4HwzBCOI2J7hQEATiVWD4Lom4bkY4S61MbJgL3Q90OQLpVKEsUWM03xtNvZS9n7JjjJE0zTG0z9lKQQybJw9B4yA68d1AujiEEtyWLwgj2Ok6VZO4kIlQNABVAAVZggA)

[image]

Comment: Re, "4 bits is rather inefficient." If it _works,_ and if it doesn't blow the budget—money, timing, board-space, etc.—then who cares whether or not it is efficient?

Comment: agreed, but OP has no specs fo budget. Did you like the simulation? @SolomonSlow

Comment: Nice simulation. Though, I must confess, I was imagining something different (OP's question leaves a lot of room for interpretation.) I imagined that PISO interfaced to a SPI peripheral in a microcontroller.